# Python re.findall() explanation

Tags: php, python, regex

Is there somebody who explains me this line of Python code:

```
matches = re.findall('( (?:[^\W\d] ){2,})', ' %s ' % s, re.UNICODE)
```

1. Am I right the pattern matches \w and non digit signs surrounded by spaces at the beginning and at the end?
2. (?: if this not captured group is here what matches are in the matches list?
3. ' %s ' % s - What means - first %s and the % s in the second param.
4. re.UNICODE
5. How to rewrite it to PHP preg_match()?

Comment: You can use https://regexr.com/ to look at the regex

Answer (score 0):

1. Use https://regexr.com/ to learn about the patterns
2. see 1.
3. Is old style formating https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting
4. re.UNICODE is a flag: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.ASCII
5. ...

Sorry I'm not a php guy

Comment: Lear more about the regexp. You are the best!